# How to grab name of a streamreader

Tags: c#

In C#, how do you grab the name or path of the streamreader

ie

```
filein = new StreamReader(@"C:\ee\fff\Desktop\spreadtool\test.csv");
```

and now I want to regex on the path, how do I reference the above.  I know filestreamer has a getname() method but does streamreader? I looked it up and it doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need the path? Perhaps you should be using FileInfo instead of trying to get to the file name through the StreamReader

Answer (score 12):

StreamReader does not have a property that contains the FilePath from which it was created. It may not be created from a file at all (it can be created from a stream). If you want the path, you should store it in a string before you create the StreamReader

```
String file = @"C:\ee\ccc\Desktop\spreadtool\test.csv"
filein = new StreamReader(file);
String path = Path.GetDirectory(file);
```

Comment: you mean path = Path.GetDirectory(filein)?

Comment: @user2521358 No not really... I mean that Path method there would take a string not a stream.

Comment: That's not completely true. If a `StreamReader` was created from a file, then the `BaseStream` is derived from `FileStream`, which has a `Name` property. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Whereas it's true that a `StreamReader` is not necessarily reading from a file, if it *is* reading from a file then the `BaseStream` derives from `FileStream`, and you can get the file name from that. The example below shows how to do it.

```
var filein = new StreamReader(filename);

string name = null;
if (filein.BaseStream is FileStream)
{
    name = (filein.BaseStream as FileStream).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What makes you so sure a given StreamReader has a name or path? You might be reading from the network, or a memorystream, serial connection, named pipe, database link... the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention why you want to access the path through the reader, so I'll assume you want to pass "something" to another method, check whether it's a specific type based on its path and then read it.

You can use [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) to pass around the file's information including its full path, size, extension etc, and [FileInfo.OpenText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext.aspx) to open a StreamReader on it, eg:

```
var fileInfo=new FileInfo(@"c:\path\to\my\file.csv");
....
using(var reader=fileInfo.OpenText())
{
    var line=reader.ReadLine();
    ....
}
```

This way you avoid strange casts to FileStream, or having to open the StreamReader (locking the file) just to pass the name around.